# Is there a way to replace the default choose file icon with a custom image background for an input field?

Tags: html, css

Since I have a PWA i can only find tutorials for uploading images using the input field.  That part is working but I'm trying to replace the default 'choose file' icon with a custom image.

Here is a pic of what I have:
[image]

I don't want the 'choose file' image to show up at all.  Also there's a default wording 'No file chosen'. I just want the image that's in the background but I haven't found anything online to shows how to replace it.

```css
  .input_pic {
    background-image: url("../../../assets/image/SpaghettiPlus2.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'false'">
                <ion-input class="input_pic" type="file"
                id="capture"
                accept="image"
                capture (change)="uploadFromFile($event, 'photo1')"></ion-input>              
            </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a click listener to the image and then load then trigger the action. I don't know if that is angular but that would be easy to do.

Comment: @nck this input field is uploading an image to a firebase backend.  This is the only way I know how to do this on a PWA.  So when you click it you can search for an image on your device and it uploads.  The click event on the actual icon doesn't provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to style the choose button with [`::file-selector-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button), however, you can't do anything about the `no file chosen` text with this solution.

*Well, you can,* by setting `color` to `transparent`, but it's not perfect.

```css
#browse::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}

#browse {
  color: transparent;
}

#browse::before {
  content: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="browse">
```

Another solution is to hide the entire `input` control and use a `label` to trigger the browse event of the input control.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
  cursor: pointer;
}

#browse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="browse" title="click to browse file"></label>
<input id="browse" type="file"> </input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply redirect the click on your image to the input, and hide the input completely:

```js
document.querySelector("img").onclick = (evt) => {
  document.querySelector("input").click();
};
```

```css
input { display: none; }
img { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
<input type="file">
```